# format-default : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

```
# CONNECT TO TENNANT
try
{
  Connect-PnPOnline `
    -Url https://bpk.sharepoint.com `
    -Credentials 'pnpdemo'
} 
catch
{
  Write-Host `
    -f red "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}

# CREATE COMMUNICATION SITE
New-PnPSite `
  -Type CommunicationSite `
  -Title 'Provisioning Assignment' `
  -Url https://bpk.sharepoint.com/sites/benn25 `
  -SiteDesign 'Blank' 

# CONNECT TO COMMUNICATION SITE
try
{
  Connect-PnPOnline `
    -Url https://bpk.sharepoint.com/sites/benn25 `
    -Credentials 'pnpdemo'
} 
catch
{
  Write-Host `
    -f red "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}

# GET SITE NAME
$SiteName = `
  Get-PnPWeb | `
  Select-Object `
  -expandProperty Title

# CREATE NEW LIST
New-PnPList `
  -Title 'Honours' `
  -Template GenericList `
  -Url lists/honours

# ADD NEW FIELD TO LIST
Add-PnPField `
  -List 'Honours' `
  -DisplayName 'Honours' `
  -InternalName 'Honours' `
  -Type Choice -Group 'Football Fields' `
  -AddToDefaultView `
  -Choices 'FA Cup', 'League Cup', 'European Cup/Champions League'

# CREATE LIST VIEW
Add-PnPView `
  -List 'Honours' `
  -Title 'Tidy View' `
  -Fields 'Honours'

# SET LIST VIEW AS DEFAULT
Set-PnPView `
 -List 'Honours' `
 -Identity 'Tidy View' `
 -Values @{DefaultView=$True}

# CREATE DOCUMENT LIBRARY
New-PnPList `
   -Title 'Player Bios' `
   -Url 'playerBios' `
   -EnableContentTypes:$true `
   -Template DocumentLibrary

# CREATE CUSTOM ROLE PERMISSION
Add-PnPRoleDefinition `
  -RoleName "Contribute (No Delete)" `
  -Clone "Contribute" `
  -Exclude DeleteListItems

# CREATE GROUP
New-PnPGroup `
  -Title "$SiteName Honours List Editors"

# CHANGE MEMBER PERMISSIONS TO READ ONLY
Set-PnPGroupPermissions `
  -Identity "$SiteName Members" `
  -RemoveRole 'Full Control', 'Edit', 'Read' `
  -AddRole 'Read'

# GET DOCUMENT TYPE
$parentContentType = `
  Get-PnPContentType `
  -Identity "Document" 

# CREATE PLAYER BIO CONTENT TYPE 
Add-PnPContentType `
  -Name 'Player Bio' `
  -Description 'Use for player bios' `
  -Group 'Football Content Types' `
  -ParentContentType $parentContentType

# CREATES NEW FIELDS FOR PLAYER BIO CONTENT TYPE
Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Squad Number' `
  -InternalName SquadNumber `
  -Type Number `
  -Required `
  -Group 'Football Content Types'

Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Player Position' `
  -InternalName PlayerPosition `
  -Type MultiChoice `
  -Choices "Striker","Defender","Midfielder","Goally" `
  -Required `
  -Group 'Football Content Types'

Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Date of Birth' `
  -InternalName DateofBirth `
  -Type Date `
  -Required `
  -Group 'Football Content Types'

Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Age' `
  -InternalName Age `
  -Type Calculated `
  -Formula ="IF(LEN([Date of Birth]) > 0,DATEDIF([Date of Birth],Today,'Y'),'0')" `
  -Group 'Football Content Types'

Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Club' `
  -InternalName Club `
  -Type Text `
  -Required `
  -Group 'Football Content Types' 

# ADDS THE FIELDS ONTO THE PLAYER BIO CONTENT TYPE
Add-PnPFieldToContentType `
  -ContentType 'Player Bio' `
  -Field SquadNumber

Add-PnPFieldToContentType `
  -ContentType 'Player Bio' `
  -Field PlayerPosition 

Add-PnPFieldToContentType `
  -ContentType 'Player Bio' `
  -Field DateofBirth 

Add-PnPFieldToContentType `
  -ContentType 'Player Bio' `
  -Field Age

Add-PnPFieldToContentType `
  -ContentType 'Player Bio' `
  -Field Club

# ADD PLAYER BIO CONTENT TYPE TO PLAYER BIO DOCUMENT LIBRARY 
Add-PnPContentTypeToList `
  -List 'Player Bios' `
  -ContentType 'Player Bio' `
  -DefaultContentType
```

When running my script I get this error:

```
format-default: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], CollectionNotInitializedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Check the comments given in this [link](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/722). Try adding something like `$view = ` before commands like `Add-PnPView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seem to of fixed the script by putting every cmdlet into a variable.

Like so:

```
# CREATE NEW LIST
$fix1 = New-PnPList `
  -Title 'Honours' `
  -Template GenericList `
  -Url lists/honours

# ADD NEW FIELD TO LIST
$fix2 = Add-PnPField `
  -List 'Honours' `
  -DisplayName 'Honours' `
  -InternalName 'Honours' `
  -Type Choice `
  -Group 'Football Fields' `
  -AddToDefaultView `
  -Choices 'FA Cup', 'League Cup', 'European Cup/Champions League'
```

No more errors :)

Comment: The trick seems to be to run the commands into variables. Thanks @BennKingy.

Answer (score 1):

Which line of the PowerShell script throw the error?

Try to use the latest version of the PnP PowerShell to check if it works.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases/tag/3.15.1911.0